# How do you persist domain entities with private data?

Tags: domain-driven-design

I've learned that it's important to decouple the domain layer from the persistence layer, and the way to do that is to declare the interface to a repository in the domain layer but implement it elsewhere—in the infrastructure layer.

Reconstitution is simple enough. I load the required data from the database and feed it to a factory, which spits out the entity.

What about saving it, though? The repository can't access private fields. In a language like C#, the fields could be declared as public properties with private setters, but that's not available in my language (I'd have to mark them as private and write the public getters by hand) and feels like a technical workaround besides; like persistence concerns are leaking into the domain layer. I shouldn't have to break encapsulation to appease a layer that sits on top, at least not according to the principles of persistance ignorance and unidirectional dependency flow.

It's worth noting my insistence on keeping the fields private stems from what I understand to be the spirit of CQRS: the entity in question is an aggregate root that I use solely for writes, while data is read elsewhere, cutting across aggregate boundaries, and assembled into a view model. Since no one (inside the domain) will be reading the entity's fields, they ought to be private. Let me know if this is a misconception and making the entity's fields publicly visible is perfectly OK.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: depends on the level of confidence you have in other layers respecting your boundaries.

#### Purpose and constraints of the domain layer

The purpose of the domain model is to ensure that, when changing your domain state, you do not put it in an invalid state. You must be able to rehydrate the domain state from your persistence store for update purposes, through a factory, as you rightly explained. When constructing the domain objects, you can either use constructors, setters, or externally acessible fields.

When changing the domain state however, you need to implement some code to ensure business invariants are not violated. This time you only can do that through setters methods. You can't use a constructor because you are not creating but mutating an object state. You can't use an externally accessible field because this would not allow code execution. If you're also using a setter for your factory, note that business state changing setters are different in purpose and implementation: the factory is progressively putting your object into shape, so the state might be invalid *during* construction. You're simply putting values into the object's internal state. The state changing setters however must ensure they never break business rules.

You must also be able to read the post-change domain state, so your persistance layer can read values to store them. This can either be done through externally accessible fields or getters.

#### Trustworthy environments

If you're in a trustworthy environment (single application maintained by a single disciplined development team), the easiest and cheapest implementation is to have domain objects with publicly accesible fields and public setters that implement the business-invariant-safe changes to your state:

- Factories will be able to construt the object by setting the fields value
- Commands will be able to validate changes by calling the setters
- Repositories will be able to read the new state by getting the fields value

#### Shared domain layer

If you're in a trustless environment, you don't want to allow other layers to access your internal state and will be required to use private fields. This will allow you to make a safer domain model but comes with a cost of additional code to write. The best way to rehydrate objects is to use a public constructor that takes scalar values, using the factory to map data from the persistence model to the constructor parameters. You can use value setters if the object construction must be done in multiple stages for instance.

You will need to implement public getters so your persistance layer can read your domain state after update. You will also need to implement public "setters" that allow your commands to mutate the domain state using values in the DTO, ensuring business invariants are not violated. But they are not actually "setters" as their purpose is to mutate the entity state rather than simply set a private field's value. Also it would have a more business oriented name, such as `Relocate` rather than `SetAddress`.

These methods may or **may not** map directly to your domain object internal's state. For instance you may have two private fields, `number` and `road` but expose address as formatted string, because it's a business invariant rule that addresses are formatted this way:

```cs
private int number;
private string road;

public string GetAddress() => $"{number} {road}";

public string Relocate(string value)
{
  value.Should().Contain(' ');
  var values[] = value.Split(' ', 2);
  int.TryParse(values[0], ref this.number).Should().BeTrue();
  this.road = values[1];
}
```

Also, if you're concerned about repositories doing nasty stuff with factories dedicated setters, you can simply implement some kind of state control:

```cs
private bool address_built = false;

public string ConstructAddress(int number, string road)
{
  if(this.address_built) { throw new InvalidOperationException(); }
  (this.number, this.road) = (number, road);
  this.address_built = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: there's a similar discussion here: [How to Access the Private State of an Entity in the Save Method of its Repository](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/448269/how-to-access-the-private-state-of-an-entity-in-the-save-method-of-its-repositor/448281#448281)

---

> making the entity's fields publicly visible is perfectly OK.

Making fields publicly visible is only a problem if you lack counter measures for the risks introduced by [Hyrum's Law](https://www.hyrumslaw.com/).

"Hiding" those details (in the [Parnas 1971](https://kilthub.cmu.edu/articles/journal_contribution/On_the_criteria_to_be_used_in_decomposing_systems_into_modules/6607958) sense) is probably more cost effective than the alternatives?  Reducing the amount of code that *can* be coupled to our transient in memory representations of information cuts down on the amount of work we need to do when those transient representations need to change.

That said, given that the useful lifetime of the information is much longer than the lifetime of our transient representations, we need *some* mechanisms that are support a round trip of information from our transient representation to our durable representation and back to the transient representation again.

The rest is just trade offs.

Some of the concerns we have:

- We'd like to be able to read the domain code without being distracted by the clutter of persistence code.
- We'd like to be able to change the details of the persistence strategy without needing to change the domain code (ie: we want the persistence strategy to be "hidden").
- We want to reduce the risk of accidental coupling of unrelated code to the persistence support - in other words, we ought to be able to change how the transient-durable exchange works without breaking unrelated code somewhere else.

Publicly visible fields are fine for the first two, but don't do so well on the last.

An alternative is to remove the read only properties from the interface of your entity, and instead provide a capability that gives access to the information but is harder to use *by accident*.

In Java, you might consider something like

```
public class Order {
   public interface SomeFactory<T> {
       T build(OrderId id, Array<LineItems> items);
   }

   public <T>
   T verb(Order.SomeFactory someFactory) {
       return someFactory.build(this.id, copy(this.items));
   }
}
```

We take advantage of generics to ensure that our dependencies all point the correct directions.  Essentially, we define a sort of double-dispatch protocol, and the domain entity knows only enough about the protocol to play its role.

Of course, given that `Order.SomeFactory` is very similar in character to the factory we use during reconstitution, we might want to instead keep the definitions of those interfaces closer together (in accordance with the principle of cohesion).

---

It gets a bit clumsier when we need the entity to track persistence metadata (ex: a copy of the database primary key).  In that case, it might look something like

```
public class Order<O> {
   O opaqueMetaData;

   public interface SomeFactory<T, O> {
       T build(O metaData, OrderId id, Array<LineItems> items);
   }

   public <T, O>
   T verb(Order.SomeFactory<T, O> someFactory) {
       return someFactory.build(
           this.opaqueMetaData,
           this.id, 
           copy(this.items)
       );
   }
}
```

If you squint, you might notice that the earlier example is a specialization of this more general case, with the implication of Void/Unit/null standing in for O.  In effect, what we are doing is adding to the transient data structure a Memento (see Gang of Four: Design Patterns) generated by, and for the benefit of, our persistence logic.

Clearly, the domain model is more aware of persistence support than in the earlier examples, though perhaps the level of awareness is still acceptable.

But it's hard to beat this for flexibility.  For example, suppose we were using an O/RM - the opaqueMetaData could *be* the data entity, with the persistence implementation of Order.SomeFactory being responsible for copying the domain information into the data entity.